# Load 64 bit integers in AVX vector

Tags: c, vector, simd, avx

I want to load a __m256 vector with 64 bit integers. But I'm unable to do so on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with gcc 7.3.0

I compiled it using the following instruction

```
gcc -mavx -o test test1.c
```

Here is a minimal example to reproduce my problem. I did try with -mavx2 as well and I got the same problem.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
__m256 avx_sreg;
 uint64_t key;

 avx_sreg = _mm256_castsi256_pd(_mm256_set1_epi64x(key));
}
```

and I get these errors -

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__m256 {aka __vector(8) float}’ from type ‘__m256d {aka __vector(4) double}’
 avx_sreg = _mm256_castsi256_pd(_mm256_set1_epi64x(key));
```

When I use 32 bit integers I get no compilation errors. Here is a minimum example

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
 __m256 avx_sreg;
 uint32_t key;

 avx_sreg = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_set1_epi32(key));  
 }
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Are you just aiming to load a 256-bit register with integers, or specifically to load the integers into a 256-bit register while having them typed as `__m256` in code (the typing reflecting packed single-precision floating-point values) as opposed to `__m256i` etc?

Comment: @SevenStarConstellation So this is my first experience with AVX instructions and I believe it is the later i.e specifically to load the integers into a 256-bit register while having them typed as __m256 in code

Comment: If you're set on filling the register with a 64-bit integer key value instead of 32-bit, you should be able to use `_mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_set1_epi64x(key))` to fill the vector and then cast. It does seem a bit of an odd usage, though, to be casting 64-bit integer keys into pairs of single-precision floats, semantically speaking.

Comment: @SevenStarConstellation- I have 64 bit geohash to store in a skip list. I am using these AVX instructions in the context of a range query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel intrinsics have 3 vector types (and the corresponding 128 and 512 bit versions):

- `__m256`: vector of `float`, used with `_mm..._ps` intrinsics
- `__m256d`: vector of `double`, used with `_mm..._pd` intrinsics
- `__m256i`: integer vector, unspecified element width.  (It's up to the programmer to mix and match different element-width operations in useful ways.)  Used with `_mm..._epi8/16/32/64` (packed integer with elements) or `_mm..._si256` (no meaningful element boundaries, e.g. `xor`)

So for integer vectors, there's only one type, but for FP vectors there are 2 different types.  In asm they use the same registers, but just like for scalar types, there are different types for different interpretations.

Once you understand this, the error message is self-explanatory:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__m256 {aka __vector(8) float}’ from type ‘__m256d {aka __vector(4) double}’
```

The right hand side of the assignment did give you a `__m256d` vector, but you're trying to assign it to a `__m256` variable.

**Presumably you want `__m256d avx_sreg = blah blah_pd` so you have 64-bit `double` elements to match your 64-bit integers.**

Comment: Great answer and thanks for guiding me in AVX intrinsics !

Comment: one final clarification on this answer. Since I have access to AVX2 I can go ahead and use _m512d. Then I can store 8 64 bit integers in one register as opposed to four now. Is that correct ?

Comment: @gansub: no, AVX1 is 256-bit float/double, AVX2 is 256-bit integer operations.   AVX512 is required for 512-bit vectors.

Comment: thank you very much. Currently on this box I do not have AVX512 support as per cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep avx